# How to use performselector to involve the function with argument after particular time period

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performselector

I am new to this iPhone app programming.
I have a function with one argument type as structure pointer. This is shown below

```
(void)responce:(structurePtr *)someData
{
......
......
}
```

I want to call this function using  `performselector method` after 5 seconds of time interval. Please tell me how to call above responce function using `performselector`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `structurePtr *` an object pointer type? or some other pointer type?

Answer (score 3):

Use:    `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay`

```
[yourObject performSelector:@selector(responce:) withObject:someData afterDelay:5];
```

Note: it is not guaranteed that your selector will be performed exactly after 5 seconds - it just specifies the **minimum** time before the message is sent to your object.