# invove the function having one argument after perticular time period using performselector

Tags: iphone, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use performselector to involve the function with argument after particular time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906019/how-to-use-performselector-to-involve-the-function-with-argument-after-particula)

I am new to this i phone app programming. I have a function with one argument type as structure pointer. This is shown below

```
-(void)responce:(structurePtr *)someData
{
......
......
}
```

I want to call this function using **performselector** method after 5 seconds of time interval.

I have used below code to perform the activity

```
[self performSelector:@selector(responce:) withObject:someData afterDelay:5];
```

this is not even called the **responce** function. By executing above performselector it is crashing and showing the EXc_BAD_ACCESS message.

please tell me why it is not calling the **responce** function.

one more thing is that it is showing one warning in above performSelector calling as "*passing argument 2 of performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: from incompatable pointer type*"

Comment: What is crash message? 
And BTW you do not need to create the same question twice - just edit or comment your first one if you have any extra details...

Comment: I am new to this form. I added some more information  in this question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that your structurePtr is a plain c structure and `performSelector:` requires 2nd parameter to be a obj-c object (an `id` type). 

     It is also may be a good policy to build your project with "Treat warning as errors" option on. Very often warning at compile time become run-time errors...